# Pass an Integer Variable Through An Animation Did Stop Method

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation

I have to pass a variable through an animation sequence, but I'm having trouble figuring out how do add it. The integer value of the yesNo is not being passed properly when I try to add it to my animationDidStop method:

```
- (void) animateStart:(NSInteger *)yesNo {

    // AT THIS NSLOG POINT THE VALUE OF yesNO VARIABLE CHECKS OK:
    NSLog(@"animateStart yesNo: %i",yesNo);

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"startMove" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    // HERE IS WHERE I TRY TO PASS THE yesNO VARIABLE:
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:yesNo:)];
    . . .

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

// I TRY TO ADD THE yesNO VARIABLE HERE:

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context yesNo:(NSInteger *)yesNo {

    // BUT THE NSLOG SHOWS THE WRONG VALUE (ALWAYS int 2)
    NSLog(@"animationDidStop yesNo: %i",yesNo);

    [self nextMethod:(NSInteger *)yesNo];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question, but in case this is of use to anyone else here goes...
The animationID variable of the setAnimationDidStopSelector method passes the NSString animationID of the beginAnimations method, which is a completely arbitrary value. So in order to pass my integer parameter, I took advantage of this exposed parameter and cast my integer parameter as a NSString and back using the code below:

```
- (void) animateStart:(NSInteger)yesNo {

    // cast the integer to a string:
    [UIView beginAnimations:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i",yesNo] context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:yesNo:)];
    . . .

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
// cast the string back to an integer:
    [self nextMethod:(NSInteger)[animationID intValue]];

}
```

Comment: You should use the context instead of the animationID. But then again, you got it working this way and it wont explode the way you have done it :D

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
- (void) animateStart:(NSInteger)yesNo
```

NSInteger is just a typedef for int:

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

so no pointer is necessary.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, but it doesn't solve the problem of passing the int variable through the other method.

Comment: Is there ever a time where this construction is proper when passing an integer into a method?                                     - (void)methodName:(NSInteger *)intVariable;                           Looks like I've been doing it wrong since day one!